# No change in Dockerfile still docker-compose --build download layers from Internet

Tags: node.js, docker, express, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) and [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/) based project which runs via [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)) and [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/).

I don't touch `docker-compose.yml`, `Dockerfile` and `package.json` file generally until there is a need of changing docker setup or adding a new module in package.json file.

I just make changes in my source code. But still `docker-compose up -d --no-deps -t 0 --build` downloads many layers from the internet. That takes a lot of time to build an image. For even making the smallest change, docker build takes time.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.33
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: mysqld
    volumes:
      - ${HOST_MYSQL_DATA}:/var/lib/mysql
    expose:
      - ${CONFIG_MYSQL_PORT}
    ports:
      - 4000:${CONFIG_MYSQL_PORT}
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${CONFIG_MYSQL_PASSWORD}

  myapp-service:
    build: myapp-service
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ${HOST_LOG_FOLDER}/myapp-service:${SERVICE_LOG_FOLDER}/myapp-service
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    expose:
      - 3000
    environment:
      CONFIG_CLIENT_ID: ${CONFIG_CLIENT_ID}
      CONFIG_CLIENT_SECRET: ${CONFIG_CLIENT_SECRET}
      CONFIG_REDIRECT_URL: ${CONFIG_REDIRECT_URL}
    depends_on:
      - mysql
```

Here is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:18
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y procps lsof ffmpeg
WORKDIR /project
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD [ "node", "--inspect", "bin/init.js" ]
```

I am building when I am making changes in source code.

```bash
docker-compose up -d --no-deps -t 0 --build myapp-service
```

Build output is

```bash
Building myapp-service
[+] Building 516.5s (11/11) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                              
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring context: 148B                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 222B                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:18                                                                                                                                                   3.1s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring context: 139.78kB                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/node:18@sha256:c85dc4392f44f5de1d0d72dd20a088a542734445f99bed7aa8ac895c706d370d                                                                                           323.6s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/node:18@sha256:c85dc4392f44f5de1d0d72dd20a088a542734445f99bed7aa8ac895c706d370d                                                                                             0.0s
 => => sha256:d9ad63743e7233472aa70512627f76b395381433585a4666d4adf5959b618294 7.24kB / 7.24kB                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => sha256:785ef8b9b236a5f027f33cae77513051704c0538bff455ff5548105c954c3b1c 49.56MB / 49.56MB                                                                                                           109.8s
 => => sha256:5a6dad8f55ae6c733e986316bd08205c8b2c41640bf8d08ff6e9bbcb6884304f 24.03MB / 24.03MB                                                                                                            60.0s
 => => sha256:bd36c7bfe5f4bdffcc0bbb74b0fb38feb35c286ea58b5992617fb38b0c933603 64.11MB / 64.11MB                                                                                                           153.8s
 => => sha256:c85dc4392f44f5de1d0d72dd20a088a542734445f99bed7aa8ac895c706d370d 1.21kB / 1.21kB                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => sha256:a52ed7aa0ea502c2e06a1066c80a8adf4163d4edc47ee3257e573cd55a7828b0 2.00kB / 2.00kB                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => sha256:4d207285f6d296b9806bd00340437406c25207412c52fcfcbf229a5ecff7bf94 211.03MB / 211.03MB                                                                                                         318.8s
 => => extracting sha256:785ef8b9b236a5f027f33cae77513051704c0538bff455ff5548105c954c3b1c                                                                                                                    0.9s
 => => sha256:e1c045e015f50783735c775373c3c715886cbd38a7d2bc2397d1d144a8db2f50 3.37kB / 3.37kB                                                                                                             110.7s
 => => extracting sha256:5a6dad8f55ae6c733e986316bd08205c8b2c41640bf8d08ff6e9bbcb6884304f                                                                                                                    0.3s
 => => sha256:7b238747a438d66daf2806f5e86e82cfa50273b92f579441c7863fb203821fc0 45.78MB / 45.78MB                                                                                                           201.3s
 => => extracting sha256:bd36c7bfe5f4bdffcc0bbb74b0fb38feb35c286ea58b5992617fb38b0c933603                                                                                                                    1.4s
 => => sha256:332e7d92ba93f359879c2e4e7a41b3148a6aac2bb8239d37511bd797ce18e1d8 2.28MB / 2.28MB                                                                                                             161.5s
 => => sha256:7718d827325f7469bba077c7f3b33d5cdd6d6aaf06ee37b89ce3a3679f223481 454B / 454B                                                                                                                 162.4s
 => => extracting sha256:4d207285f6d296b9806bd00340437406c25207412c52fcfcbf229a5ecff7bf94                                                                                                                    3.4s
 => => extracting sha256:e1c045e015f50783735c775373c3c715886cbd38a7d2bc2397d1d144a8db2f50                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => extracting sha256:7b238747a438d66daf2806f5e86e82cfa50273b92f579441c7863fb203821fc0                                                                                                                    1.0s
 => => extracting sha256:332e7d92ba93f359879c2e4e7a41b3148a6aac2bb8239d37511bd797ce18e1d8                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => extracting sha256:7718d827325f7469bba077c7f3b33d5cdd6d6aaf06ee37b89ce3a3679f223481                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [2/6] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y procps lsof ffmpeg                                                                                                                                      133.4s
 => [3/6] WORKDIR /project                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [4/6] COPY package*.json ./                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [5/6] RUN npm install                                                                                                                                                                                   54.2s
 => [6/6] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s 
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                       2.2s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                      2.2s 
 => => writing image sha256:114495444a75e9be20d1f75eda5d900b720e95a020bef152cd160f5a6c23f743                                                                                                                 0.0s 
 => => naming to docker.io/library/trimpixelbackend_meetingbot-service                                                                                                                                       0.0s 
Recreating mybackend_myapp-service_1 ... done
```

`docker.io/library/node:18` always need internet. Why caching is not getting used for `node:18` image?

How can I prevent need of interent and download when I am only changing my source code(javascript files)?

Comment: Are you running this locally or in a CI pipeline?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle: locally

Comment: if you run it and see it pulling everything then immediatly run it again do you then see it using the cached layers?

Comment: The `node:18` image was changed only 9 hours ago. If you have anything on your system that is either purging the image, or re-pulling the image then your docker file will see the new image hash for `node:18` so will then have to invlidate all the cache layers and build it all from scratch again

Comment: @ChrisDoyle: How can I prevent need of internet after first setup. I want to ignore if there is change in `node:18` image.

Comment: You can use the format `<image_name>:<tag>@<digest>` which will always get that specific snapshot of that tag. I.E `FROM node:18@sha256:c85dc4392f44f5de1d0d72dd20a088a542734445f99bed7aa8ac895c706d370d`. You can get the digest from the image pull or from dockerhub

Comment: Thanks a lot :) This will solve my problem